# Degenerate States in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: terminology, quantum-mechanics

In his book on quantum mechanics in the chapter on perturbation theory Dirac says in a footnote:

> A system with only one stationary state belonging to each energy-level is often called *non-degenerate* and one with two or more stationary states belonging to an energy-level is called *degenerate*, although these words are **not very appropriate from the modern point of view**.

I have two questions about this:

1) Why did Dirac deem the terms *(non-)degenerate* inappropriate?

2) Why do we, with our even more modern point of view, still use them?

Comment: Maybe he didn't like the derogatory implication of "degenerate" ?

Comment: Possibly. My first association was with the Nazis use of the term 'degenerate art'.

Comment: I doubt PAMD was referring to cultural connotations of the time---he was not the type to pay attention to such. He may have been deferring to  category epimorphisms in Hilbert space. I doubt catastrophy theory was around at the time. Merging energy levels "degenerate" to a single one, and have their "degeneracy lifted" by running the relevant parameter backwards. He may have objected to the inappropriate final, irreversible slant of the term.

Comment: @CosmasZachos [Dirac's book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Quantum_Mechanics) was published in 1930. It was a year before von Neumann embedded quantum mechanics into Hilbert spaces (inspired by Dirac's book) and they entered physicists' vernacular. Dirac may be alluding to the old quantum mechanics of Bohr, where energy was the only quantum number, so multiple states meant degenerate eigenvalues. In general, there are multiple quantum numbers and true degeneracy would mean multiple states even when *all* of them are equal.

Comment: @ Conifold. Fair enough... you appear more knowledgeable than me on this history. PAMD hardly ever modernized his own language there... cf "the standard ket" instead of the vacuum...

Comment: The footnote in question is actually absent from the first edition https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.177580/page/n171. The earliest point it could have been added was '35  as I was unable to find a scan of the second edition. It's present in the third from '47.

Comment: @CosmosZachos: I don't think Dirac knew anything about Category Theory. He was a physicist not an algebraic topologist and category theory didn't really get going until Grothendieck got hold of it. What on earth has catastrophe theory (that is the studying degenerate singularities) got to to with degeneracy in QM? I mean they use the same terms but the concepts are completely different.

Comment: @CosmosZachos: Please don't tell me I'm getting all 'metaphysical' again. This is wearing very thin now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my interpretation of what Conifold’s unchronological comment may have been trying to say. The term “degeneracy” was first introduced by Schwarzschild ([1916](http://www.archive.org/stream/sitzungsberichte1916deutsch#page/548), p. 550) in the context of “old quantum theory”. (Credit by Sommerfeld ([1921](https://archive.org/details/atombauundspekt00sommgoog/page/n521), p. 500).)

In ([**1927**](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN252457811_1927?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B5%5D%7D), p. 4) von Neumann “embedded quantum mechanics into Hilbert spaces” after participating in Hilbert’s [1926/27 seminar](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PID=GDZPPN002271788) (and reading Dirac’s papers). Thereafter, degeneracy took the meaning of operator eigenvalue multiplicity, which is what Dirac must be referring to as “the modern point of view” in his book (1935 or 1947).

So Dirac may be objecting to the old QM word having been imported in this way — as opposed to using a “more appropriate” new one to mean “multiplicity > 1”. But no handy alternative emerged, so we still use degeneracy. (It would be interesting to see if similar uses in linear algebra, or algebraic geometry, pre- or post-date this episode.)